# @keyframes slider transition

Tags: css, css-animations, gallery, transition

I have a css keyframes slideshow that switched from the 5th item to the 1st too quickly. I'm not sure why this is happening but you'll notice when project 5 slides to the screen, it switches back to project 1 quickly. I would like that to be displayed for the same duration as the others. If theres any way to keep that last project up, I would really appreciate the help.

```
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 1</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 2</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 3</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 4</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 5</div>
</div>
</div>
</figure>
</div>

@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 

div#slider { overflow: hidden; }

div#slider figure .page { width: 100vw; float: left; }

div#slider figure { 
position: relative;
width: 500vw;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 10;
animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}

.page {
display: flex; 
justify-content: center; 
}

.project {
display: flex; 
align-items: center; 
}
```

Comment: sure did, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because when looping through the items difference between 100 percent and 0 percent is just 1 percent so the animation has to happen in just 1 percent of the duration. Just dividing the duration (percents) equally solves the issue.

```css
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
10% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: -100%; }
30% { left: -100%; }
40% { left: -200%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
60% { left: -300%; }
70% { left: -300%; }
80% { left: -400%; }
90% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 

div#slider { overflow: hidden; }

div#slider figure .page { width: 100vw; float: left; }

div#slider figure { 
position: relative;
width: 500vw;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
text-align: left;
font-size: 10;
animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}

.page {
display: flex; 
justify-content: center; 
}

.project {
display: flex; 
align-items: center; 
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 1</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 2</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 3</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 4</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="page">
<div class="project">
  <div class="col project-img">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x350">
  </div>
  <div class="col project-info">info 5</div>
</div>
</div>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
15% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: -100%; }
35% { left: -100%; }
40% { left: -200%; }
55% { left: -200%; }
60% { left: -300%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
80% { left: -400%; }
95% { left: -400%; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When answering questions with code try to keep in mind that OP as well as other people, that might come searching for similar problem, would benefit much more from explanation of how code works rather than just raw code.